# FileMaker Server will not start - host unreachable (10502) - SSL error

Tags: ssl-certificate, filemaker

Running FileMaker Server 18. A combination of a in process SSL certificate update and a system reboot has left our FileMaker server in a state that it will not start.

The FileMaker Server logfile simply shows:

> Error  701 BHL-DBSERVER    Database Server process has terminated abnormally.

The Windows event log shows the following error:

> SECURITY: Error 213 occurred when FileMaker Server attempted to set the context for the imported SSL certificate. Because of this security error, the Database Server will now stop. Remove the imported SSL certificate by using the "fmsadmin certificate delete" command, then use Admin Console to import a valid SSL certificate.

However, when I run `fmsadmin certificate delete` from an admin cmd console, it returns:

> Errors: 10502 (Host unreachable)

I'm not really sure what to do at this point. Pretty much all of the fmsadmin commands return the host unreachable error

Answer (score 3):

Solution ended up being to delete all of the *.pem files from the FileMaker Server CStore directory. Just running the included "uninstall.bat" was not enough. This allowed FM to restart with it's default security certificates and I was able to import a new SLL cert.

Comment: If still not working after deleting the *.pem files, try restarting FileMaker Server. That worked for me, then I could sign in to the Admin Console.